# Importing an entire SQL Server table into R

Tags: sql, r, data.table

I have a table in SQL Server and would like to import the entire table into R to perform some work.

I'm trying to find the best path for this since the table sizes could be large (~60 million)

There is a bcp Utility command line utility in SQL Server and that's one option.

But does anyone have other suggestions?

Comment: Sql server has slow drivers (at least those free ones), probably because it is not an open source DB. I would go with csv export, and then fread that in R.

Comment: For me, neither msqlodbc nor freetds are awesome for speed. For larger data, like @jangorecki suggested, I use an external call to `sqlcmd` for queries and `bcp` for uploads (various reasons, none of them happy, working around unbelievable "features" in both). `fread` is by far the faster CSV reader, `vroom` a close second (in my 2M-row tests).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sqlcmd` for bulk queries. It is far faster than anything Microsoft's ODBC drivers (or FreeTDS) can do.

If your query is (say)

```sql
SELECT Id, Field1, Field2 FROM TableName WHERE Field1 = 'QUUX'
```

Then your command line would be something like:

```bash
sqlcmd -S serveraddress -d databasename \
  -U username -P '*PASSWORD*' \
  -W -s , -o out.csv \
  -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT Id, Field1, Field2 FROM TableName WHERE Field1 = 'QUUX'"
```

(If your server is on a non-standard port, then use `-S serveraddress,portnumber`.)

I tend to not like R's `system` (or `system2`, a thin veneer), instead preferring the [`processx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/processx/index.html) package for its safer way of handling command line arguments.

```r
bgquery <- processx::run("sqlcmd",
    args = c("-s", "serveraddress", "-d", "databasename",
             "-U", "username", "-P", "*PASSWORD*", "-W", "-s", ",", "-o", "out.csv",
             "-Q", "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT Id, Field1, Field2 FROM TableName WHERE Field1 = 'QUUX'"),
    error_on_status = FALSE, echo_cmd = FALSE, echo = FALSE)

# check its stdout, it can be rather verbose
tail(bgquery$results$stdout)

# check the return value, typically "0" for command success
bgquery$results$status

# if error, look at the error output, something might be in the stdout above, too
bgquery$results$stderr
```

At this point, read in the file:

```r
x <- data.table::fread("out.csv", nrows = 3, na.strings = c("NA", "", "NULL"))
```

Note: `sqlcmd` does *not* quote the values. So for instance,

```sql
SELECT 'hello,world' as A
```

using `sqlcmd` will return

```csv
A
hello,world
```

which is obviously broken. If this is a problem, you may be stuck. `bcp` is another option with its own problems, so it's not a perfect replacement.